# Angular/Reactive Forms - Add or Delete an list of FormControl - Binding template (With demo)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a `matSelect` since I can select a number from 1 to 10, depending on the number I have to display the same number of`matInput` with a *ngFor. The number selected by default in the select is 1 (so we have a one `matInput` by default too)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Number of winners to reward" [value]="selected" (selectionChange)="selectNumber($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let emailNumber of totalEmailsNumber" [value]="emailNumber">
      {{ emailNumber }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div formArrayName="mails">
  <mat-form-field *ngFor="let email of form.get('mails').controls; let i = index">
    <textarea matInput [formControlName]="i"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

to add the default FormControl of the first `MatInput` I do:

```
this.form.controls['mails'] = this.fb.array(this.emailsNumber.map(() => new FormControl('', Validators.required)));
```

Which works, but I can not manage the logic to add another `FormControl` or to delete it if for example the user chose 10 in the select then changed it to 4,
and manage the binding in the template.

Im also wondering is `*ngFor="let email of form.get('mails').controls` is a good practice?

---

> Here's a [**Minimal StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yn4xfa) to work with

Comment: And what if the user selected 10 first and entered in all 10 and then selected 4? What do you expect to happen there?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Delete the last 6 and leave only the first 4 `matInput`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  totalEmailsNumber: number[];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.totalEmailsNumber = this.createCustomLengthArray(10);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      mails: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  get mails() {
    return (<FormArray>this.form.controls['mails']);
  }

  selectNumber(emailNumbers) {
    const difference = this.mails.length - emailNumbers;
    difference > 0 ? this.removeMails(difference) : this.addMails(difference);
  }

  removeMails(difference) {
    this.createCustomLengthArray(difference)
      .forEach(item => this.mails.removeAt(this.mails.length - 1));
  }

  addMails(difference) {
    this.createCustomLengthArray(difference)
      .forEach(
        item => {
          this.mails.push(this.fb.control(null, Validators.required));
        }
      );
  }

  createCustomLengthArray(length) {
    return (new Array(Math.abs(length)))
      .fill(null)
      .map((item, index) => index + 1);
  }
}
```

---

And in the Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select 
          placeholder="Number of winners to reward" 
          [value]="selected" 
          (selectionChange)="selectNumber($event.value)">
            <mat-option 
              *ngFor="let emailNumber of totalEmailsNumber" 
              [value]="emailNumber">
              {{ emailNumber }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div formArrayName="mails">
        <mat-form-field 
          *ngFor="let email of form.controls['mails'].controls; let i = index">
            <textarea 
              matInput 
              [formControlName]="i">
      </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-for-form-array-and-controls-in-it) for your ref.

Comment: it works !
what was the point of changing the `createCustomLengthArray` method?

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri, I think your implementation would also suffice. My approach is something that I've been using for quite some time. But I really like your approach. Less work to do in your case I'd say. Just use yours. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use simple for loop and use either `push` or `removeAt` (that takes the index) for the FormArray. Don't try with `splice`, it won't work ;)

Also you wouldn't want to use `(selectionChange)="selectNumber($event)"` Since that will be fired twice. Instead use `valueChange`:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (valueChange)="selectNumber($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let emailNumber of totalEmailsNumber" [value]="emailNumber">
      {{ emailNumber }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then the `selectNumber()` could look like this:

```ts
selectNumber(value) {
  let formArr = this.form.get('mails') as FormArray;
  // user has chosen less fields than already exists
  if (formArr.controls.length > value) {
    const toRemove = formArr.controls.length - value;
    for (let i = 0; i < toRemove; i++ ) {
      // remove last element
      formArr.removeAt(formArr.length - 1);
    }
  } else {
    const addFields = value - formArr.controls.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < addFields; i++) {
      formArr.push(new FormControl(''));
    }
  }
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqpsmi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

And as for the last question...

```ts
*ngFor="let email of form.get('mails').controls
```

Is perfectly good! I use that, or a getter.